# When I save my image as JPEG in Photoshop and I use it in my program and I run it, I see the lines in the image as slash

Tags: android, image

When I save my image as JPEG in Photoshop and I use it in my program and I run it, I see the lines in the image as slash and not 
as the continuous line.For example,it displays as ( - - - - - - - - - - - -)
and not as (_________________________________) and some lines are obliteration.
While in main image is not in this case.

I set this setting during saving the image.My device resolution is about 3 inch.

[image]

**activity-main**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/fff"   >
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.eexample.oo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }
}
```

A picture of the my device(Because the black circle is impact)
[image]

and the following image is same but in computer:
[image]

Comment: Some code would be nice to see. You should really be using PNG unless there is a lot of detail in the images. Even then I would recommend PNG over JPG. At a guess, the image is being re-sized by the App or Android and the lines are being loss during that re-size. Try making a "fat" line and see what happens.

Comment: When I use PNG-8, I see lines with black background. When I use PNG-24, I see black background completely without displaying my image.   When I use GIF, I see black background with lines.only when I use JPEG, I see my main image and It displays thick lines well but the thin line not.It seams JPEG is best option.But only it works for thick lines well.

Comment: How are you using the image exactly in your program? Show some code please.  Are you saving a single image or are you using the correct `drawable-XYZ` folders? I say this because in the screen shot you have `2550px` by `3300px` which is a really large image.

Comment: I put more information.

Answer (score 0):

We have a device with a resolution of 240 * 320 pixels, So we should set the following setting for solve the problem:

In Photoshop, go to File/Save For Web, and set the W and the H as the following image:
[image]

Because my device is GT-S5360 and it has 240 * 320 pixels.The problem will be solved.